# Proof environment: problem with \popQED and \pushQED{\qed}

Tags: amsmath, theorems

I was trying to replace `.` with `:` in the proof environment and after trying a lot of answered questions here, I got [I'm using amsmath]

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{:}]\ignorespaces}
    {\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse}
\makeatother
```

but this isn't working very well for me. After dozens of tries, I came up with

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{:}]\ignorespaces}
    {\endtrivlist\@endpefalse}
\makeatother
```

So, what is the problem with `\pushQED{\qed}` and `\popQED`? Without both of them, the code works, but I can't get the qed square.

Comment: What's "not working well" in the first case?

Comment: And [welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: An easier way to get a colon is to say `\renewcommand{\proofname}{Proof:}`. Something more complex is needed if you use `babel`, but the idea is the same.

Comment: @egreg

Not working well is one of this message per proof

"! Undefined control sequence.
\\proof [#1]->\par \pushQED
{\qed } \normalfont \topsep 6\p@ \@plus 6\p@ \re...
l.167 T"

Thank you for the good reception!

And yes, I think I'm going to need the "something more complex", because I'm using [brazil]{babel}. Also, I commented the babel and tried the solution you gave and I got "Proof:.".

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work without any problem; note that you *must* load `amsthm`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm} % for the proof environment

\addto\captionsbrazil{\renewcommand{\proofname}{Demonstra\c{c}\~ao:}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Exercise for the reader.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternative and perhaps better version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm} % for the proof environment

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]
  {\par\pushQED{\qed}%
   \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
   \trivlist
   \item[\hskip\labelsep
         \itshape
         #1\@addpunct{:}]\ignorespaces}
  {\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Exercise for the reader.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Another different version with patching (but it's just the same as the one before).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm} % for the proof environment

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\@addpunct{.}}{\@addpunct{:}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Exercise for the reader.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Man, thank you. Your post helped me in another direction. I tried to use amsmath and discovered it was conflicting with 

    \usepackage[amsmath,amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
    \theoremstyle{change}    
    
that I was using to put the number before the newtheorem name. Then, I used the amsthm and \numberswap and I got it solved. Thank you a lot!

Comment: I have the same problem and same warming (with the suggested correction \renewenvironment....) because I replaced the amsthm package with ntheorem.

Comment: @user39158 That's a completely different situation and doesn't fit in this question. But I never recommend `ntheorem`.