# How to remove the dot in the proof environment (using ntheorem package)?

Tags: theorems, punctuation, ntheorem

`\begin{proof} something \end{proof}` produces

> *Proof. something*

and I want

> *Proof: something*

The solution suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31354/how-to-remove-the-in-the-proof-environment) produces an error if one uses the `ntheorem` package instead of `amsthm` as mentionned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95818/proof-environment-problem-with-popqed-and-pushqed-qed/95849?noredirect=1#comment677326_95849). Although I don't remember the reason I chose `ntheorem` over `amsthm`, I won't risk myself changing it...

I also tried the following in vain:

```
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain} 
\theoremseparator{:} (other irrelevant font modifications also)
\newtheorem{beweis}{Proof}
\let\proof\beweis
```

Comment: Um, the `ntheorem` package does not define an environment called `proof` *unless* some options are set when the package is loaded. Could you tell us which options you're specifying when loading the `ntheorem` package?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know. I loaded `[amsmath,amsthm,thmmarks]`

Comment: If you don't like the look of the `proof` environment that's set up by providing the `amsthm` option, you shouldn't specify this option to begin with.

Comment: I'll think about it some day. at the moment I have no idea why I loaded it, I must have copied it from some other answer in tex.stackexchange...

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `amsthm` option, and use something like this in your preamble:

```
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theoremseparator{:}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that. In my opinion,  the O.P. should not use the `amsthm` option. It's very easy to mimic the general layout of `amsthm` and change what one wants to change.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this is a all in one question answer but I can say that I despaired ever finding the answer as I have (almost) no understanding of the codes and I felt I had to share.

I copied the definition of the "nonumberplain" theoremstyle (which I found at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ntheorem.sty  and opned with notepad ++), called it differently, modified it and made the "proof" environment use that style:

```
\makeatletter
 \gdef\th@styledemo{% I chose the name "styledemo"for the style
  \def\theorem@headerfont{\normalfont\itshape\small}\itshape% Here you can actually further modify the "header" and body font
 \def\@begintheorem##1##2{%
  \item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1:]}% Here I replaced the . with :
 \def\@opargbegintheorem##1##2##3{%
 \item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ (##3):]}}% same replacement here

\newenvironment{beweis}[1][Proof]{% the proof environement already exists so I chose another one
 \th@styledemo  % here I call the theoremstyle define above
 \def\theorem@headerfont{\itshape\small}% Here I don't really understand but nevertheless write the same specification for the font again...
 \normalfont\itshape\small
 \theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{_\blacksquare}}
\@thm{proof}{proof}{#1}}% here one should keep proof, don't ask why...
{\@endtheorem}
\makeatother
\let\proof\beweis % replace the environment proof with beweis
```